# Ruby on Rails: Problem installing gitorious in Ubuntu 9.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ubuntu-9.04, gitorious

I seem unable to install Gitorious. I am trying not to install Ruby Enterprise Edition, but apart from that I have been following the instructions for Ubunut (there were some errors but I have gotten around those). I have installed a number of missing packages and gems, but now I am stuck when I try to migrate the database. I get the following error:

rake aborted!

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Trace looks like this:

```
/var/www/gitorious/config/environments/production.rb:39:in `load_environment'
/var/www/gitorious/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `load_environment'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
/var/www/gitorious/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:379:in `load_environment'
/var/www/gitorious/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:137:in `process'
/var/www/gitorious/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/var/www/gitorious/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/var/www/gitorious/config/environment.rb:13
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:32:in `require'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19
```

My understanding is I this is claiming I'm missing some dependency, but I have checked that the dependencies in /var/www/gitorious/config/environment.rb have been installed.

I also put a print in custom_require.rb to print the path variable and the last print is "active_support/dependencies".

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is or how I could debug this further? Can I print the exact missing dependency somehow? Is it even possible to install gitorious without installing the entire Ruby Enterprise edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked about this from the Gitorious discussion group and the reason is the default gitorious.yml file only has settings for test environment. By copying those settings to the production environment, I got this problem fixed.